# iron-router request.body returns empty if posting through Postman

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using the Chrome Postman plugin to test my meteor app API endpoints, everytime I try to POST some data using Chrome Postman >> form-data tab, iron-router request.body returns empty.

Only when I use the x-www-form-urlencoded tab in Chrome postman, request.body returns data, can someone tell me please what I am missing / doing wrong here and how can I parse data sent using the form-data tab in Chrome Postman? Thanks

Code I am using to build my Meteor app endpoints is based on this example typically  [Meteor REST example](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-rest-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, but I had the same issue and switch between undefined and [Object] object when i construct a rest api with meteor with postman.

I resolve it by processing the query instead the body like this

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('methodExample', {
    path: '/api/test/',
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {

        // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
        var requestMethod = this.request.method;

        if(requestMethod == 'POST'){
            console.log('>> HTTP Verb POST ');
            console.log(
                    JSON.stringify(this.request.query)      
            );
            this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            this.response.end( 
                    JSON.stringify(this.request.query)
            );
        } else if (requestMethod == 'GET'){
            console.log('>> HTTP Verb GET ');
            this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            this.response.end('GET :)');
        } else {
            console.log('Unsupported HTTP Verb ! ');
            this.response.writeHead(501, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            this.response.end('Unsupported HTTP Verb ! ');

        }
    }
}); });
```

I hope it will help